# Should I remove post excerpt from our homepage mobile experience?

Tags: usability

I had a discussion here with my partner that wants to remove all posts excerpts from our homepage and archive listings when acessed by mobile devices. The argument is that the homepage will be shorter and more content will be seen above the fold.

**Here is what we do now:**

[image: This is what we do now]

**Here is the proposal:**

[image: This is what was proposed]

I am not convinced that this is a good approach. What I know about excerpts is that they influence readers to click-through. The proposed homepage looks polluted with lots of non-related blocks together. The presence of the excerpt appears to attenuate this confusion.

I could not find any articles related to this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting proposal, and I have seen similar designs work both ways. I would say that what you should be doing is **A/B testing** this, and seeing what results you get back.

Even if you can find articles on the matter, it's no pain at all really to A/B test these days and this kind of change is the perfect candidate for an A/B test.

Make sure you know what metrics you are looking to measure and what and when success can be determined, but there are a bunch of good articles on A/B testing, like this one https://vwo.com/ab-testing/ - have a particular look at 'The A/B testing process' section.

While this isn't an answer to which design you should use, I think you'll find that (in this case) this is going to be a better way for you to decide what to go forward with, rather than based on the answers you might get here. Not to say you won't also get some valuable insights from the community.

Comment: In your A/B testing, ensure your sample size is large enough to draw meaningful conclusions.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am setting some Analytics events so we can track the differences. Will update here about the conclusion, for future viewers!

Answer (score 1):

I agree with previous comment try A/B testing. 
For myself without the excerpt is better in an aesthetic way but :

- Maybe your readers will want to know where they'll landing after clicking, before they clicked.
- this is a good way to resume all the news in three lines. Like that your users can read their feed of news without being annoyed with other interactions than scroll.

You will have to choose between aesthetic and convenient ! (maybe you should change the design of the excerpt ;) )

Comment: Thank you guys. I am setting some Analytics events so we can track the differences. Will update here about the conclusion, for future viewers!

Answer (score 1):

If this is an existing product, let your analytics guide you. What kind of click-through do the post-excerpts get? If very few users drill down via this pathway, removing it is very low-risk.

Comment: Thank you guys. I am setting some Analytics events so we can track the differences. Will update here about the conclusion, for future viewers!